# Programmatically catch app opening / closing

Tags: macos, applescript, services, daemons

Is it possible, via an AppleScript, a background service or daemon, or any other programmatic way, to catch the following events:

- a specific app (eg Aperture, Excel ...) being launched,
- an app being closed or quitting,
- an app going to the foreground or background ?

Purpose would to be change some system state/pref  (eg keyboard layout, screen profile etc) in an app-dependent manner.

Of course, suggestions of existing solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain notifications of applications being launched and quit. Apple's **TN2050: [Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2050/_index.html)** provides the detail.

The best method for general purpose tracking is with `NSWorkspace` and its `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` and `NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification` notifications.

I do not believe there is a trivial means to implement these TN2050's methods in AppleScript. You will likely need to write a small Objective-C/Cocoa application or use a third party tool.

Comment: Thanks. My Cocoa is a bit old but I should have thought of notifications. Seems to be the right tool indeed.